# Writing Mysql Query more efficient

Tags: mysql, performance

How can I make this below Mysql query more efficient ?

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT crm_task_id,
   table_header_id  
FROM
   table_details  
WHERE
   table_header_id  IN (
      SELECT
         table_header_id  
      FROM
         table_header  
      WHERE
         crm_campaign_id =196  
         AND crm_campaign_post_code_id  IN (
            SELECT
               crm_campaign_post_code_id  
            FROM
               crm_campaign_post_code  
            WHERE
               is_display_operator  IN (
                  1, 0 
               )  
         )  
         AND g_user_id  IN (
            SELECT
               g_user_id  
            FROM
               crm_user  
            WHERE
               is_active =1  
         )  
         AND DATE_FORMAT( created,  '%Y-%m-%d' )   BETWEEN  '2015-12-01'  AND  '2016-01-04'  
      )  
      AND crm_task_id NOT   IN (
         SELECT
            crm_task_id  
         FROM
            table_details  
         WHERE
            table_header_id  IN (
               SELECT
                  table_header_id  
               FROM
                  table_header  
               WHERE
                  crm_campaign_id =196  
                  AND crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000  
            )  
         )
```

**table_header columns :**

```
| table_header_id           | bigint(20)  
| created                   | datetime     
| updated                   | datetime    
| createdby                 | bigint(20)   
| updatedby                 | bigint(20)   
| is_active                 | char(1)     
| crm_user_session_id       | bigint(20)   
| crm_campaign_id           | bigint(20)   
| crm_post_code_categ_id    | bigint(20)  
| value                     | varchar(128) 
| crm_campaign_post_code_id | bigint(20)   
| crm_filter_id             | bigint(20)  
| g_user_id                 | bigint(20)  
| session_time              | int(100)
```

**table_details Columns:**

```
| table_details_id | bigint(11)  
| table_header_id         | bigint(11) 
| created                   | datetime    
| updated                   | datetime  
| createdby                 | bigint(11)
| updatedby                 | bigint(11) 
| is_active                 | smallint(5)
| crm_contact_id            | varchar(60)
| crm_task_id               | bigint(11)
```

the above query takes more than 2 seconds to return result, Please can anyone rewrite this query to return result faster !!!

Comment: Can you see if it might be possible to use joins instead of subqueries inside the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: okay I will try and let you know

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its slow when using join, Header table contains 1,94,323 and details table contains 8,70,842 records

Comment: A large number of records is precisely the situation where one would want to use joins rather than subqueries as a means of restricting records at some point during the execution of a query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT td.crm_task_id,
   td.table_header_id      
FROM
   table_details td      
join
   table_header th 
      on th.table_header_id = td.table_header_id 
      and th.crm_campaign_id =196 
      and th.crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000      
join
   crm_campaign_post_code ccpc 
      on ccpc.crm_compaign_post_code_id =  th.crm_campaign_post_code_id 
      and ccpc.is_display_operator IN (
         1,
      0 ) 
      and DATE_FORMAT( created,
      '%Y-%m-%d' ) BETWEEN  '2015-12-01' AND  '2016-01-04'      
   join
      crm_user cr 
         on cr.g_user_id = ccpc.g_user_id 
         and cr.is_active = 1
```

Comment: I think the query mentioned by @Naveed is a optimized one. Just one clarification I need is on first JOIN condition i.e.

   on th.table_header_id = td.table_header_id and th.crm_campaign_id =196 and th.crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000

should it be replace with

on th.table_header_id = td.table_header_id and th.crm_campaign_id !=196 and th.crm_post_code_categ_id =1000

Comment: @MohitAggarwal thanks for your feedback and correction.

Comment: Execution times increased when we use IN or nested query so instead of that, we can use joins.

Comment: Ah ok. Actually I have a web portal www.everything.pk which have cities, brands, stores with respect to brands and cities and areas and I was using same as yours query (like IN or nested query) and page load or execution was too slow up to 3,4 seconds. while after some research, I updated query to JOINS and query execution time was .03, .05 like this. so that's why I was sure that your issue will also be resolved using JOINS.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT crm_task_id, td.table_header_id
    FROM table_details td
    WHERE table_header_id 
    JOIN table_header th
    ON td.table_header_id = th.table_header_id
    AND th.crm_campaign_id =196
    JOIN crm_campaign_post_code c
    ON c.crm_campaign_post_code_id = th.crm_campaign_post_code_id
    AND is_display_operator IN ( 1, 0 ) 
    JOIN crm_user u
    ON u.g_user_id = c.g_user_id
    AND is_active =1
    AND DATE_FORMAT( created,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
    BETWEEN  '2015-12-01'
    AND  '2016-01-04'
    WHERE u.crm_task_id  NOT 
    IN (
    SELECT IFNULL(crm_task_id,0)
    FROM table_details
    WHERE table_header_id
    IN (
    SELECT table_header_id
    FROM table_header
    WHERE crm_campaign_id =196
    AND crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000
   ))
```

Comment: it takes 2.45 seconds

Comment: Header table contains 1,94,323 and details table contains 8,70,842 records

Comment: do you use indexes in tables ?

Comment: Yes , table_details contains index for column "crm_task_id" , table_header table contains indexes on g_user_id, crm_filter_id and group index on crm_campaign_id,crm_post_code_categ_id,crm_campaign_post_code_id

Comment: one more thing can you use subquery with join may be it will help you.like 
`JOIN (select table_header_id,...... from table_header where  crm_campaign_id =196) as th
ON td.table_header_id = th.table_header_id`

Comment: in this query you have filtered data with table may be it reduce time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT crm_task_id, table_header_id
FROM table_details
WHERE table_header_id
IN (
    select table_header_id From 
    (
    SELECT table_header_id
    FROM table_header
    WHERE crm_campaign_id =196
    AND crm_campaign_post_code_id
    IN (

        select crm_campaign_post_code_id from (
        SELECT crm_campaign_post_code_id
        FROM crm_campaign_post_code
        WHERE is_display_operator
        IN ( 1, 0 )
        ) temp2
    )
    AND g_user_id
    IN (
        select g_user_id from (
        SELECT g_user_id
        FROM crm_user
        WHERE is_active =1
        ) temp3
    )
    AND DATE_FORMAT( created,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) BETWEEN  '2015-12-01' AND  '2016-01-04'
    ) as temp_1
)
AND crm_task_id NOT IN (
    SELECT crm_task_id FROM table_details WHERE table_header_id
    IN (
        select table_header_id From (
        SELECT table_header_id
        FROM table_header
        WHERE crm_campaign_id =196
        AND crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000
        ) temp4
    )
)
```

Comment: above query takes more than 3 secs

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; it does not optimize well.  Instead turn it into a `JOIN`.  For example:

```
SELECT  crm_task_id
    FROM  table_details
    WHERE  table_header_id IN (
        SELECT  table_header_id
            From  
              ( SELECT  table_header_id
                    FROM  table_header
                    WHERE  crm_campaign_id =196
                      AND  crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000 ) temp4 )
```

-->

```
SELECT  crm_task_id
    FROM  table_details AS d
    JOIN  table_header AS h ON d.table_header_id = h.table_header_id
    WHERE  h.crm_campaign_id =196
      AND  h.crm_post_code_categ_id !=1000
```